# Importing Joomla 1.5.23 to Drupal 7 by using Feeds

Tags: feeds, migrations

I'm trying to migrate Joomla 1.5 to Drupal 7 by using [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) Module. I have tried the "[Joomla to Drupal](https://drupal.org/project/joomla)" with no luck. And the "[Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate)" module requires some PHP coding, which I'm not an expert on this.

Question 1 - So, my question is which phpMyAdmin database for "Node Import" when I import CSV to Drupal? I know "jos_users" is for the "User import". What about the rest of them?

Question 2 - How to import Joomla user password by using Feeds? The password format seems different.

Question 3 - How and where can I import the url formatting?

For details, please see below of my Joomla phpMyAdmin database list.

Thanks!

```
jos_banner
jos_bannerclient
jos_bannertrack
jos_categories
jos_components
jos_com_file_index
jos_com_file_index_errors
jos_contact_details
jos_content
jos_content_frontpage
jos_content_rating
jos_core_acl_aro
jos_core_acl_aro_backup
jos_core_acl_aro_groups
jos_core_acl_aro_map
jos_core_acl_aro_sections
jos_core_acl_aro_wtf
jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map
jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map_wtf
jos_core_log_items
jos_core_log_searches
jos_funrecaptcha
jos_groups
jos_jce_groups
jos_jce_plugins
jos_jcomments
jos_jcomments_custom_bbcodes
jos_jcomments_reports
jos_jcomments_settings
jos_jcomments_subscriptions
jos_jcomments_version
jos_jcomments_votes
jos_jobline_jobs
jos_jobline_jobs_types
jos_jobline_types
jos_jxcomments_comments
jos_jxcomments_ratings
jos_jxcomments_ratings_members
jos_jxcomments_threads
jos_jxtended
jos_menu
jos_menu_types
jos_messages
jos_messages_cfg
jos_migration_backlinks
jos_modules
jos_modules_menu
jos_newsfeeds
jos_plugins
jos_polls
jos_poll_data
jos_poll_date
jos_poll_menu
jos_redirects
jos_sbxss_categories
jos_sbxss_slides
jos_sections
jos_session
jos_stats_agents
jos_taxonomy
jos_taxonomy_config
jos_taxonomy_elements
jos_taxonomy_filters
jos_taxonomy_map
jos_templates_menu
jos_users
jos_weblinks
jos_xmap
jos_xmap_ext
jos_xmap_sitemap
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never considered how you would use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import from a database, but it works great for migrating content when that content is in a "feed".

If you have to use the DB, then there is [Feeds SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_sql) and [Feeds DB](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_db), but I think both require you to write a query. That said, if you are using phpMyAdmin then when you "open" any of those tables phpMyAdmin will show the query it's running.

If you are able to expose your content as an xml/rss feed, a JSON feed, , or etc. then thing become very straight forward.

Using the [Feeds Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/feedspreview) module may help you get your mapping correct.

You should be able to import the node alias (path) along with the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use cms2cms.

I don't have experience with it, but i must says'it costs you some.

To 10 pages it's for free, after that you need to pay.

http://www.slideshare.net/CMS2CMS/how-to-migrate-from-joomla-to-drupal

Comment: Thank you @d1m5n. I think it will cost me a lot. The site that I'm migrating is over 1000pages.

Comment: should be a better way to do it then

Comment: I have worked with the drupal to drupal migrate module. I have written my own modules for this. You can write your import script for this. Also i have noticed a other module: https://drupal.org/project/joomla (it's in alpha though)

Comment: I just migrated few Joomla sites to Drupal for the past few weeks by using Feeds Module. Everything seem fine, except the password. PS: We tried "Joomla to Drupal" module with no luck. It stops around 50%, that's why we used Feeds Module. Actually, these sites we were migrated are over 8000+ pages.

Comment: Good to hear that almost everything has worked out

Comment: @H-L can you give me an idea how did you use the feeds module? Do you mean i have to create a custom php code to write an xml for all contents and then map this to drupal feeds module? 

I am trying out the Joomla to Drupal module and it exported the contents but it did not include the comments and the actual images from those contents.

Comment: @jan No, you just need to export Joomla data into CSV format, then import into Drupal by using Feeds module. What's more important is that, you need to know the data mapping from export to import. Hope this help.

Comment: @jan the problem using Feeds module is the password migration. You can try to use "Joomla to Drupal" module first, which is https://www.drupal.org/project/joomla

Comment: @H-L Thanks for coming bacK! Yes I'm actually using the Joomla to Drupal now but unfortunately only migrates the native contents like jos_contents, categories and users. But I'm still using it anyway. I may have to edit the module itself to accommodate all other data from tables made by some plug ins (property plugin for property data).

Comment: @H-L Adding to that above, Do you have any suggestions on how I can migrate the other language versions of the contents as well? I'm planning to just edit the module which is not good but I am so inclined to edit it anyway to serve multilanguage migration too.

Comment: @jan Sorry, I have not done anything with language migration. If that is part of the field, then you need to set up a field on that content type before migrating. However, I dont think Joomla to Drupal can do much. You need to use "Feeds" module or "Migrate (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) " to be more effective. PS: You need hand code PHP on "Mirgate" module

Comment: @H-L I really want to use the Migrate module since it is more flexible to do coding but the lack of my experience with drupal module works makes it difficult as I have deadlines to follow. Were you succesfull with Feeds module? If so, was it able to handle all types of contents from Joomla? Even contents from other plug ins? Your input will really really help. Thanks again!

Comment: @jan I dont know what type of plug-in you have. You can migrate any data from Joomla, as long as it is in your database. What "Feeds" module does is allow you to map data into Drupal. Hope this video can help you with Feeds module (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4)